# Google docs, Add value to (sum) if equal to

Tags: excel, google-docs, lookup, vlookup

So, I've been doing a personal project to track some progress in a video game and I got to a point that's a little weird.

I have a spreadsheet, seen here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ah9Vzcgj-i9udEdzbnpLUktUM3lrRUc1dXJwNkNmUXc&usp=drive_web#gid=0

As you can see there are pieces of "currency", which have values applied to them on the data validation sheet.   Now, assuming that I'm entering the names of the currency, how can I get that to add to a summed value?

In a full fledged programming language what I'd do is use a hashmap, where the value of the cell ("Orb of Regret" for example) would simply key to some value, then just increment for each cell in a range... but when it comes to excel / docs I'm at a little bit of a loss for how to do that.

Goal:
To match the currency by name from cells E3:G100, match their name against the values in Data Validation A2:A17, and return the value that matches from Data Validation B2:B17, then sum that value for the entire range (E3:G100)

If you have any questions please feel free to ask.  Pretty sure the issue would be the same in excel as it is here, so I'm tagging as both excel and docs.

Comment: For the first row, do you want a separate value for E3, F3 and G3? or are you trying to get the value for all three at once?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of to accomplish this is to add another column(say insert one after col G in the 'Dominus Runs' sheet, which would make the new col H - I'll use that for my example). Then in H3, put this formula:

`=sum(iferror(vlookup(E3,'Data Validation'!A:B,2,0),0),iferror(vlookup(F3,'Data Validation'!A:B,2,0),0),iferror(vlookup(G3,'Data Validation'!A:B,2,0),0))`

Then, where you want your total for all of it, just put `=sum(H:H)`